# WinUI3: How to reference controls in viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I'm using TemplateStudio to build my project

In **Views > TestPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="FluentQQ.Views.TestPage"
    ...>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="MessageInput" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And in **Views > TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
using FluentQQ.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace FluentQQ.Views;

public sealed partial class TestPage : Page
{
    public TestViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public TestPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<TestViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to get the contents of the TextBox "MessageInput"
So, in **ViewModels > TestViewModel.cs**, I use

```
MessageInput.Text
```

But it dosen't work

```
CS0103  The name 'MessageInput' does not exist in the current context
```

*I know this question may very simple，but forgive me for just being a beginner*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the `MessageInput` control does not exits in **TestPageViewModel*. With MVVM, usually, you should use bindings to get data from your view.

Just to make sure we are on the same page, in this case:

- TestPage.xaml is the **View**
- TestPage.xaml.cs is the **code-behind**
- TestPageViewModel.cs is the **ViewModel**

1. Install the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) nuget package. This will make your life easier  if you are using the MVVM pattern.
2. In your ViewModel, **TestPageViewModel**:

```cs
// This class needs to be "partial" 
// for the "CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" source generators.
public partial class TestPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // The source generators will create 
    // an UI interactable "SomeText" property for you.
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string someText;
}
```

3. In your code-behind, **TestPage.xaml.cs**:

```cs
public sealed partial class TestPage : Page
{
    public TestViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    public TestPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<TestViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

4. Then in your view, **TestPage.xaml**:

```xml
<TextBox
    x:Name="MessageInput"
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

That's all. **SomeText** will be updated every time you change the text in the `TextBox`.

By the way, you can access the `TextBox` directly from code-behind. Just make sure you use `x:Name` to name it.

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
MessageInput.Text = "some text";
```

Comment: Thank you veeeeeeery much, again, for helping me so many times